# Google Chrome cannot submit form with display:none

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

The Submit button on this form does nothing unless I remove `style="display:none"` from the `template=row` div.  Why??

*(The `name` of each form control is populated dynamically by javascript, however, to simplify troubleshooting, I ran the form without the javascript and the problem boils down to whether or not that `display` tag is there).*

This is what Chrome console says:

```
bundleAn invalid form control with name='' is not focusable.
bundleAn invalid form control with name='label' is not focusable.
bundleAn invalid form control with name='unique' is not focusable
```

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="/add/bundle">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="singular" placeholder="Singular Name" required>
        <input type="text" name="plural" placeholder="Plural Name" required>
    </p>

    <h4>Asset Fields</h4>

<div class="template-view" id="template_row" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" data-keyname="name" placeholder="Field Name">
    <input type="text" data-keyname="hint" placeholder="Hint">


    <select data-keyname="fieldtype" required>
        <option value="">Field Type...</option>
    </select>

    <input type="checkbox" data-keyname="required" value="true"> Required
    <input type="checkbox" data-keyname="search" value="true"> Searchable
    <input type="checkbox" data-keyname="readonly" value="true"> ReadOnly
    <input type="checkbox" data-keyname="autocomplete" value="true"> AutoComplete
    <input type="radio" data-keyname="label" value="label" name="label" required> Label
    <input type="radio" data-keyname="unique" value="unique" name="unique" required> Unique
    <button class="add" type="button">+</button>
    <button class="remove" type="button">-</button>
</div>

<div id="target_list"></div>

    <p><input type="submit" name="form.submitted" value="Submit" autofocus></p>

</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot be submitted"?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the question to make clearer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cause seems to be HTML 5 [constraint validation](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#constraint-validation) - it's the `require` attribute. Chrome has started supporting this with it's recent versions.

Apparently it seems like this is a [backward compatibility issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=45640), but you can fix it with setting the `formnovalidate` attribute for your submit button.

I assume that this is actually a security feature that prevents submitting supposed user data by submitting manipulated, hidden content, this quote points in that direction:

> If one of the controls is not being rendered (e.g. it has the hidden attribute set) then user agents may report a script error.

Your inputs are of type `text`, so their purpose is to let users enter data, submitting their content while hidden is something that a user probably wouldn't want.

If you still want to submit hidden inputs while using client validation, I would suggest using `<input type="hidden">` instead - I could imagine that there is no error on validation there because they are intended to be invisible.

Comment: that DOES fix the problem, thank you.  However, now I can't have validation client side, right?  No problem if that's the case, but I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something that still allowed me to validate the required fields.

Comment: I edited the post - I could imagine that `input type="hidden"` could still pass form validation.

Answer (score 1):

I made a JSFiddle to explore your problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TmFkC/5/), and I managed to fix it by adding **checked** to your radiobutton inputs like so: `<input type="radio" data-keyname="label" value="label" name="label" required checked>`. In your code above, the radio buttons are not checked, but since they are marked as `required` the form is failing validation and Chrome refuses to submit the form.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, that is a good workaround, but since the javascript I excluded actually clones the controls, I don't really want the radios checked by default, else they would keep cancelling the user's legitimate choice every time the controls are cloned.