# multiple submit buttons won't postback on aspx - only last button

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

On my aspx page I have two `fieldsets`, each wrapped with an `<asp:Panel DefaultButton="...">` that have their own `<input type="submit">` buttons. Here's an abbreviated version...

```
<div id="content">...</div>
<asp:Panel runat="server" id="formPanel1" DefaultButton="form1SubmitButton"> 
    <fieldset>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="textbox1"/>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="textbox2"/>
        <asp:Button runat="server" id="form1SubmitButton" OnClick="form1SubmitButton_OnClick"/>
    </fieldset>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel runat="server" id="formPanel2" DefaultButton="form2SubmitButton"> 
    <fieldset>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="textbox3"/>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="textbox4"/>
        <asp:Button runat="server" id="form2SubmitButton" OnClick="form2SubmitButton_OnClick"/>
    </fieldset>
</asp:Panel>
```

Only the last submit button `form2SubmitButton` will postback, the other button does nothing when clicked. **I have simplified the code above but I should mention that each form, Panel included, is kept in a separate user control that is registered on the aspx.**

**UPDATE:** After some more research I've figured out that the submits are not working because of validators on the another fieldset on the master page. That fieldset is for signing into the site, so it is needed. Thoughts?

Comment: That shouldn't even compile/run. The ID's must be Unique in that context. I suspect too much as been "abbreviated". In any case one really common issue of "postbacks not running" (but a postback still occurs!) is caused by the Control Tree not being restored correctly. Also, does what does "Does Nothing" mean? Is a request sent at all? Does it error on a call to __dopostback? Are there UpdatePanels? Is there any validation?

Comment: each of these fieldsets are actually in separate user controls. So the id's being the same shouldn't make any difference. I'll change it for this example. Can you explain, or point me in the right direction to find out more info about the control tree not restoring correctly?

Comment: You may want to check to make sure your validation groups are not preventing one of them from submitting.

Comment: @pst "Does Nothing" means when I click the submit button nothing happens, no postback, no js errors, nothing. No no update panels and my validation is client side via a jquery plugin, and that is working properly.

Comment: @bflemi3 Now that's .. interesting. Any custom event handlers? Any client-side validation (does it work with the validation removed)? Is there an inline "onclick" attribute attached? Is it inside a form element? (And is there only one form element on the page?)

Comment: @pst just OnClick handler for each button. I've never tried actually removing the validation, I'll do that and see if that works. No no inline onclick handlers on the client side. Yes it's inside the form that raps the page since it's an aspx page :)

Comment: @pst still doesn't work with jquery validation plugin commented out

Comment: @bflemi3 No sneaky stuff with the form onsubmit?

Comment: @pst I have other stuff I have to work on this morning but sometime today I'm going to just create a new page, stick both forms (simplified versions) and go from there. I'll post back my results...

Comment: @pst alright ran a quick test, I have validators on a another fieldset on the masterpage for logging into the site. That fieldset has validators on the username and password textboxes and when I commented them out (`<%-- --%>`) it worked. So, how to get around that, because I need them?

Comment: @bflemi3 You can disable validation for the the individual controls CausesValidation="false". Also, you can disable client-side validation (but keep server-side validation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it has to do with HTML5 constraint validation. I figured this out because in chrome, from the console, I was getting the error `An invalid form control with name='...' is not focusable`. This led me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183692/google-chrome-cannot-submit-form-with-displaynone) post. I added the html5 attribute `formnovalidate="formnovalidate"` to the submit buttons and everything works just fine (*tested in chrome v20.0.1132.57, firefox v14.0.1, IE9 v9.0.8112).

So to recap, here's the answer...

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="submit1" OnClick="submit1_OnClick" text="Submit" formnovalidate="formnovalidate"/>
```

Comment: Interesting .. I guess, only use hidden controls for hidden data ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As PCasagrande mentioned, make sure your validation groups match the default button and all validators. Specially for your logging part.

Example:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlUpdateInfo" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnUpdateInfo">

  <ASP:TEXTBOX id="txtZip" runat="server"></ASP:TEXTBOX>   
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="reqvalZipSignUp" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="txtZip" ValidationGroup="btnUpdateInfo" />                       

  <asp:Button ID="btnUpdateInfo" runat="server" ValidationGroup="btnUpdateInfo"  />

</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: I'm confused by 'validation groups match the default button', can you explain that?

Comment: ah yes, that's what I thought you meant. Thanks for elaborating Remy