# Hidden/Disabled fields disappear from req.body (Express JS bodyParser)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I have not been able to find the answer to this question.  When using NodeJS, Express, and the Express Bodyparser - and the rest of my MEAN stack for that matter - I run into an issue with both hidden and disabled fields: they do not show up in the req.body object when submitting a form.

If I understand correctly, the bodyparser aspect of express is actually taken from another project.  Regardless, I have not really been able to figure out why these fields are being removed or how to stop this from happening.  I suspect it might have something to do with methodoverride, but enabling/disabling this has no effect on the fields in question.

So.. for myself and future googler's: what is happening here?

Here's some code, as requested: 
JADE:

```
form(action="/admin/users/edit", method="post", ng-submit='registerUser($event)', name='form', novalidate)
    .row(ng-show="ifweareupdating")
        label(for="_id") _id:
        input(type="hidden", id="_id", name="_id", ng-model="newUser._id")
        input(type="text", id="_notHiddenId', name="_notHiddenId", ng-model="newUser._id")
```

EXPRESS:

```
app.post("/admin/users/edit", pass.ensureAdmin, userRoutes.editUserPost);
```

userRoutes:

```
exports.userRoutes.editUserPost = function(req,res,next) { 
    console.log(req.body._id) // logs undefined
    console.log(req.body._notHiddenId) // logs actual id
}
```

Comment: please post some code on how you create your form and send the data to the server.

Comment: Disabled form input fields aren't submitted by the browser. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355728/values-of-disabled-inputs-will-not-be-submited.

Comment: Right you are about the disabled form input fields.  Any idea about the hidden fields? (I'll update with a code snippet - I'm not doing anything complicated)

Comment: What do you mean "hidden" field? `<input type="hidden" name="field">` should work; `<input name="field" style="display:none">` probably won't. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318428/submit-form-fields-inside-displaynone-element.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183692/google-chrome-cannot-submit-form-with-displaynone might help too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Express.  Only *successful controls* are serialized and sent by the browser when a form is submitted.

[The HTML spec defines what makes a control successful.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2)

> A successful control is "valid" for submission. Every successful
>   control has its control name paired with its current value as part of
>   the submitted form data set. A successful control must be defined
>   within a FORM element and must have a control name.
>
> However:
>
> - Controls that are disabled cannot be successful.
> - If a form contains more than one submit button, only the activated submit button is successful.
> - All "on" checkboxes may be successful.
> - For radio buttons that share the same value of the name attribute, only the "on" radio button may be successful.
> - For menus, the control name is provided by a SELECT element and values are provided by OPTION elements. Only selected options may be
>     successful. When no options are selected, the control is not
>     successful and neither the name nor any values are submitted to the
>     server when the form is submitted.
> - The current value of a file select is a list of one or more file names. Upon submission of the form, the contents of each file are
>     submitted with the rest of the form data. The file contents are
>     packaged according to the form's content type.
> - The current value of an object control is determined by the object's implementation.
>
> If a control doesn't have a current value when the form is submitted,
>   user agents are not required to treat it as a successful control.
>
> Furthermore, user agents should not consider the following controls
>   successful:
>
> - Reset buttons.
> - OBJECT elements whose declare attribute has been set.
>
> Hidden controls and controls that are not rendered because of style
>   sheet settings may still be successful.

Your problem is actually Angular.  [Apparently](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/pjZm4KMEoyc/4d-GSiLvzuQJ), it does not set the `value` of hidden inputs.